# How to make this list case-insensitive and list them alphabetically in primeng dropdown?

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

For example, I have an object of the array as follows:

```
const persons = [
   {value: "Jason"},
   {value: "Ana"},
   {value: "iron"},
]
```

Currently, the result is:

[image]

How to make this list case-insensitive and list them alphabetically in primeng dropdown?

[image]

I have tried `sortField` attribute in primeng dropdown - no luck.

```js
<p-dropdown
    [options]="persons"
    optionLabel="value"
    sortField="compareFn()"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson"
></p-dropdown>
```

```js
compareFn(a: any, b: any): number {
    if (
      a.value.toLowerCase() > b.value.toLowerCase()
    ) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.value.toLowerCase() < b.value.toLowerCase()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [PrimeNG Dropdown docs](https://primeng.org/dropdown), I don't see the `sortField` is available.

You can just perform sorting in the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.persons.sort(this.compareFn);
}
```

```
<p-dropdown
  [options]="persons"
  optionLabel="value"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson"
></p-dropdown>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/djjcjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-basic-demo.ts)